# Can't get Image data through req.body, I am using postman and sending post request with binary data that is an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using postman and sending a post request with binary data as an image, The image data is obtained in request.body but I am not able to write it in  a file.
Code for  the same is : fs.createWriteStream('/home/user/Downloads/Documents/4.jpg').write(req.body); 
 But the data is copied  in hexadecimal format and I am not able to open the image.

Comment: try converting that data in base64

Comment: @M.Chandna Please paste the response in detail, also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following code helps, but this is what i have, hope you can play-around it and solve your problem

```
router.post('/api/data/logo/:name',upload.single('logo'), (req, res) => {
  var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
  var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
  req.body.imageUrl = req.file.path || '';
  req.body.contentType = req.file.mimetype || '';
  req.body.size = req.file.size || '';
  req.body.logo = Buffer(encImg, 'base64') || '';
  if (!req.userId) return res.status(405).send(JSON.stringify({error: 'Not logged in'}));
  dataController.image(req.userId, req.params.name, req.body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).end();
    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({form: data}));
  });
});
```